# Sourcemap to original SCSS file

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass, minify

I'm `using Webpack 4` with the plugins `MiniCssExtractPlugin` and `OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin` to extract `SCSS` files and minify the `main.css` file in production. I have source mapping enabled in my config file like so:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
        style: './src/scss/main.scss'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                 test: /\.css$/,
                 use: [
                     MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                     { loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, sourceMap: true } }
                 ]
             },      
             {
                 test: /\.scss$/,
                 use: [
                     'style-loader',
                     MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                     { 
                         loader: 'css-loader', 
                         options: { 
                             url: false, sourceMap: true 
                         } 
                     },
                     { 
                         loader: 'sass-loader', 
                         options: { 
                             sourceMap: true 
                         } 
                     }
                 ]
             }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            filename: "main.css"
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            test: /\.js($|\?)/i,
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
            cssProcessorOptions: {
                map: {
                    inline: true
                }
            }
        }) ,
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
        })    
    ]
}
```

In the console, it does give the line where a CSS rules originates from, but in the bundled `main.css` file, rather than invididual scss files i.e. `_layout.scss`, `_buttons.scss`.

***Question***

What configuration do I add in order to display where the CSS rule originates from, rather then where it is located in the bundled `main.css` file?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: You mean `sass-loader`?

Comment: Yes :) You can achieve what you need just by using sass compiler source maps and the right configuration for the browser.

Comment: Have I not achieved this through setting the options property `sourceMap` to `true` for `sass-loader`? With also devtool set to `source-map`? First time using Webpack :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see on your `sass-loader` configuration, you're already getting the source maps for yous `scss` files (to verify that you need to have a file with the same name as you css, but with a `.map` on its name), so the only thing you will need is to peroperly configure your browser to load and use the source maps. This example uses Google Chrome:

1. Open dev tools
2. Click the gear icon or three dots to open settings (top right corner)
3. Under General (or Preferences), look for the “Sources” section. In that section, select “Enable CSS source maps”.
4. Make sure the accompanying “Auto-reload generated CSS” is also enabled (if available). This last step helps to reload the CSS when it changes. Think of it like a live reload feature for the CSS alone.
5. Navigate to your localhost server, inspect any element on your page.
6. In the developer tools, choose the Sources tab.
7. In the file tree on the left hand side, right-click your stylesheet and select “Map to file system resource…”. This will bring up the file search dialog. Select the appropriate file (your stylesheet). In some newer versions of Chrome, the file should be loaded automatically using the `/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */` reference
8. Restart the developer tools.

That should work. Let me know. Otherwise i will fine tune the quick tutorial.

Comment: Got to right clicking on Map to file system, but the option isn't there? Thank you for your time and help btw

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott yes, in prior versions on Chrome, the map loads automatically (i'm using OSX Chrome latest version). Does the compiled css has the `/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */` line pointing to your source map? Is the source map in the same folder?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott in the new versions, if the source map is detected, if you go to sources, select the desired file, then in the center section, where the source code is displayed, a message will appear: "Source map detected"

Comment: Can't see the source map in directory or in console :/

Comment: Then the source maps are not being compiled at all. Double check the `sourceMap` configuration https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader